# Error DataFill Local Db C#

Tags: c#

Hola tengo este **`connection string`** para conectarme a una base de datos `localDb` desde `MSSS` me puedo conectar normal pero cuando trato de ejecutar este código me sale error:

Este es el `string` de conexión:

```
string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\SQLPRINTERBI;AttachDbFilename=C:\ProgramData\SQLPrinterBI\DATA\SQLPrinterBI.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

Este es el código que utilizo para ejecutar un `Stored Procedure` y traer como resultado un `dataset`.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(procname, conn);
                for (int i = 0; i <= parmname.Count - 1; i++)
                {

                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + parmname[i].Split(',')[0], parmname[i].Split(',')[1]);
                }
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
                da.Fill(ds);

            }
        }
```

Este es el **error**:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error relacionado con
>   la red o especÃ­fico de la instancia mientras se establecÃ­a una
>   conexiÃ³n con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontrÃ³ el servidor o
>   Ã©ste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es
>   correcto y que SQL Server estÃ¡ configurado para admitir conexiones
>   remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Se produjo un
>   error de Local Database Runtime. La instancia de LocalDB especificada
>   no existe. )    en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager
>   sqlAuthProviderManager)    en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    en
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    en
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    en
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    en
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    en
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)    en
>   WindowsService.DynamicCallDB.calldb(String procname, List`1 parmname) 
>   en WindowsService.Service1.WorkProcess(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs
>   e) ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Error
>   Number:-1983577849,State:0,Class:20

Alguien sabría por que se presenta este error ?

Muchas Gracias

---

Este es el código que estoy implementando con los cambios que tu me dijiste.

```
public static DataSet calldb2(string procname, List<String> parmname)
    {


        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ModErrorHandler err = new ModErrorHandler();

            err.WriteLog("Entro");

            string cs = @"Server=(local)\SQLPRINTERBI;Initial Catalog=SQLPrinterBI;User ID=sa;Password=Password1.@Smartdi;Integrated Security=True";



            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                err.WriteLog("Entro conexion");
                err.WriteLog(procname);
                err.WriteLog(conn.ToString());
                SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(procname, conn);
                err.WriteLog("4");
                for (int i = 0; i <= parmname.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    err.WriteLog("5");
                    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + parmname[i].Split(',')[0], parmname[i].Split(',')[1]);
                }
                err.WriteLog("6");
                sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                err.WriteLog("7");
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

                da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
                err.WriteLog("8");

                da.Fill(ds);
                err.WriteLog("9");
            }
        err.WriteLog("10");
        return ds;
    }
```

y esta es la salida que obtengo de mi aplicacion

```
31-Oct-2019 20:55:45 :Operation Started_____________________!
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :10/31/2019 8:56:45 PM
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :Workprocess
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :Sart Execution to SP GetTimePeriod
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :Entro
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :Entro conexion
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :sp_schedularDetails_GetTimePeriod
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :4
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :6
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :7
31-Oct-2019 20:56:45 :8
31-Oct-2019 20:57:00 :Catch Workprocess
```

y me esta saliendo este error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance- 
specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was 
not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that 
SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network 
Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** este es un sitio en Español, traduce tu pregunta

Comment: De casualidad, ¿ese archivo tiene los permisso de lectura y escritura por parte del usuario que utiliza el SQL Server?

Comment: aqui muchas formas de conectarse https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentando conectarte a una instancia de SQL Server local en la opcion *Data Source*, pero a la vez en el connection string le estas especificando que monte un archivo de base de datos (.mdf) en la opcion *AttachDbFilename*. Para hacer la conexión debería ser una o la otra.

Para especificar que base de datos de la instancia agrega en la cadena de conexión el parámetro *Initial Catalog* seguido del nombre de tu base de datos. De la siguiente manera:

```
string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\SQLPRINTERBI;Initial Catalog=SQLPrinterBI;Integrated Security=True";
```

Verifica también el prefijo que pones en el Data Source ya que (local) es para las instancias locales y (localDb) es solo para instancias de Sql Express (locales tambien pero de SqlExpress)

Comment: pero tendria entonces que ponerlo de la siguiente manera 

@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\prueba;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False";

y como hago para especificarle la base de datos a la cual se va a conectar.

yo creo una instancia de LocalDb y posteriormente creo una base de datos como haría para poner esa base de datos en el connection string.

Comment: Agregarias un parametro mas a la cadena de conexion _Initial Catalog_ donde especificas la base de datos. Quedaria de la siguiente manera "Data Source=(LocalDB)\prueba;Initial Catalog=<base_de_datos>;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False"

Comment: Obtengo nuevamente el error 50 es necesario poner usuario y contraseña?